# Distance from center to out of ortographic camera view in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, frustum

I have a scene with an ortographic camera and I need to find the distance from the center of my world axis to the external in way to move an object outside the camera view. I know how to calculate the frustum of the camera but I'm not able to retrieve the Z distance for moving objects outside. Help anybody? [image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? Are you trying to find the minimum distance from the camera center to the edge of the viewport? Or are you trying to find where the red line intersects the edge of your viewport? Or something completely different from those? Also, please include any code you can share, and indicate what you've already tried to resolve the problem.